# Change order/position of Gutenberg inspector control panel

Tags: block-editor

I'm adding a new panel to a Gutenberg block through the `editor.BlockEdit` wp.block filter.

```
<InspectorControls>
   <PanelBody title={ __( 'New Settings' ) } initialOpen={ false } >
   ...
   </PanelBody>
</InspectorControls>
```

The new panel appears on top of the default panels. Is there any way to change the order? To make it show below other panels? I did not find any documentation about this..

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

```
    <InspectorControls>

       <PanelBody title={ __( 'Settings One' ) }>
       </PanelBody>

       <PanelBody title={ __( 'Settings Two' ) }>
       </PanelBody>

       <PanelBody title={ __( 'Settings Three' ) >
       </PanelBody>

    </InspectorControls>
```

If you insert multiple Panelbody like I did in above code. You will have multiple inspector controls with first one being ope by default. Change the panelbody accordingly to match your desired order.

Comment: Is this really an answer to the question?

Comment: @ChristineCooper I do not think it does. If you have all your instances of `Panelbody` in one place, you can indeed manage their order like above. However, OP seems to want to insert an extra panel with the `editor.BlockEdit` filter. In this case, the above snippet will not be useful imo.

Answer (score 1):

Again very late for such a question, but since there is no answer YET..

There is **undocumented** attribute `__experimentalGroup` which can be used on `InspectorControls` like this:

```
<InspectorControls __experimentalGroup="typography">
// panels inside
</InspectorControls>
```

You can find list of groups by inspecting with React developer tools, some common are `color` and `typography`. By applying above attribute, setting is applied on the end of group. Some css tweaking may be needed, as default panels have a little different css classes.